# db::raw adding is null in query

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to use laravel query builder like:-

```
$users = DB::table('baid_collection')
         ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as total_collect,collection_limit_c'))
         ->join('users_cstm', 'baid_collections.assigned_user_id', '=', 'users_cstm.id_c')
         ->where(DB::raw("assigned_user_id = '$userId' and DATE(date_entered)=CURDATE()"))
         ->groupBy('assigned_user_id')
         ->get();
```

This query should be like

```
select sum(total) as total_collect,collection_limit_c from `baid_collections` inner join `users_cstm` on `baid_collections`.`assigned_user_id` = `users_cstm`.`id_c` where assigned_user_id = '15426608-3ea5-f299-7a80-601bd06be2d9' and DATE(date_entered)=CURDATE() group by `assigned_user_id`
```

But last run query showing me

```
 select sum(total) as total_collect,collection_limit_c from `baid_collection` inner join `users_cstm` on `baid_collections`.`assigned_user_id` = `users_cstm`.`id_c` where assigned_user_id = '15426608-3ea5-f299-7a80-601bd06be2d9' and DATE(date_entered)=CURDATE() is null group by `assigned_user_id`
```

In query `is null` giving problem i dont want is null in query

Comment: instate of `CURDATE()` use `Carbon::today()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use whereRaw instead of where like

```
$users = DB::table('baid_collections')
         ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as total_collect,collection_limit_c'))
         ->join('users_cstm', 'baid_collections.assigned_user_id', '=', 'users_cstm.id_c')
         ->whereRaw("assigned_user_id = '{$userId}' and DATE(date_entered)=CURDATE()")
         ->groupBy('assigned_user_id')
         ->get();
```

It's creating a problem due to where needs atleast two parameters and you are just passing one parameter

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it helps, write whereDate instead of add date in raw query.
if you are not using Carbon, you can also use `php date("Y-m-d")`, method to get date

```
DB::table('baid_collection')
                ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as total_collect,collection_limit_c'))
                ->join('users_cstm', 'baid_collections.assigned_user_id', '=', 'users_cstm.id_c')
                ->where(DB::raw("assigned_user_id = '$userId'"))
                ->whereDate("date_entered", "=", Carbon::now()->toDateString())
                ->groupBy('assigned_user_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$users = DB::table('baid_collection')
         ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as total_collect,collection_limit_c'))
         ->join('users_cstm', 'baid_collections.assigned_user_id', '=', 'users_cstm.id_c')
         ->where(DB::raw("assigned_user_id = '$userId' and DATE(date_entered) = '".date('Y-m-d')."'"))
         ->groupBy('assigned_user_id')
         ->get();
```